# IIS URL Rewrite Response Header

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use a reverse proxy with IIS to point to an Express appliction.  I've got the URL Rewrite working pointing my dnsname.domain.com:80 to localhost:3001 but I have a need to have the request headers in express to see my dnsname.domain.com instead of localhost:3001 for req.headers.host

I've been messing with outbound rules and trying to set HTTP_HOST to the domain value but I haven't been able to get around this

[IIS URL Rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFweu.png)

Is what I'm wanting to do possible?  Our login system at works needs to see dnsname.domain.com to function properly so passing localhost:3001 is causing it to fail

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/modifying-http-response-headers#modifying-the-inbound-rule-to-preserve-the-host-header

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Application Request Routing has an option to preserve the original host header: `preserveHostHeader`.

This option is by default false. You can enable it with below command:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config -section:system.webServer/proxy /preserveHostHeader:"True" /commit:apphost
```